# Did someone die in a dutch oven?

Tags: mortality

[This article](http://www.ronsonwriter.com/content/view/69/9/) has been going around social media being touted as news.

> Husband Convicted Of Manslaughter After Dutch Oven Goes "Horribly Wrong"

According to the story:

> The case for the prosecution argued for the charge of Murder, putting it to the court that, ... Mrs Flannery was ... in bed and unwinding for sleep, she was suddenly and forcibly pinned under the duvet by Mr Flannery, who sealed the edges with his weight while simultaneously releasing an enormous bolus of flatulence, which displaced all the available oxygen so that Mrs Flannery passed out nearly instantly, and was dead within 30 seconds

Is it possible to kill someone with a fart? Did this event actually happen?

Comment: 30 seconds without oxygen to kill someone is a bit on the short side.

Comment: Mythbusters might be relevant here, they did an [episode about flatus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MythBusters_%282006_season%29#Facts_About_Flatulence) where they showed that this is effectively impossible.

Comment: @rob This news article challenges that. The question is who is more reliable, ronsonwriter or mythbusters?

Comment: @Coomie Given the choice between a website that I've never heard of and a TV show that at least spells out how they are testing things? Mythbusters.

Comment: Ronson Writer is fiction.

Comment: The "Peckham crown court" mentioned in the article does not exist. I strongly suspect that English law doesn't have the "second degree manslaughter" that the article mentions, only voluntary and involuntary manslaughter.

Comment: I read the title and thought "of course someone would die if you managed to stuff them into a small cast iron pot" :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, this is satire. But, it's possible that it happened and hasn't been reported anywhere.

You need to look at the source of the original article. In this case, it's a site called [The Ronson Writer](http://www.ronsonwriter.com/).

They are a spoof news site along the lines of The Onion and The Shovel. Their [About](http://www.ronsonwriter.com/content/view/15/22/) page says:

> The Ronson Writer is an online newspaper and collective blog about the absurd state of modern popular culture. **Part satire**, part opinion and part vaguely-verified factual reporting, but always (we hope) at least mildly amusing.

(Emphasis mine.)

Other "news" articles include other obviously fictional stories [like](http://www.ronsonwriter.com/content/view/77/9/)

> A study released today reveals that the London Metropolitan Police are 7 times more likely to arrest a black cloud of smoke, such as the one that loomed over London last week, than a common white or gray smokestack from, say, a middle-class suburban house-fire.

Comment: also, the 2 quotes have nothing to do with each other. A Dutch Oven is utterly unrelated to flatus/farting except if you use it to cook something that makes you fart :)

Comment: @jwenting http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dutch%20oven

Comment: @jwenting English Language & Usage question related to ["Dutch X" phrases](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110497/is-dutch-wife-one-of-those-dutch-words) (disclaimer: question written by me)

Answer (score -2):

Hoax. The photo in the article is of Brisbane (Australia) [Barrister Stephen Kleim](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2014-02-11/barrister-stephen-keim-outside-the-brisbane/5253250) taken by Liam Kidston of AAP.

Comment: That is useful circumstantial evidence that the story isn't a well-referenced news story, but it isn't terribly definitive that it is a hoax.